# Deprecation and feature warnings for SBT project definition files

Tags: sbt

I am getting *deprecation* and *feature* warnings when compiling my SBT project *definition* (i.e. the files inside the `project` directory). SBT version is 0.13.0.

I do not get more info on these by setting `scalacOptions := Seq("-feature", "-deprecation")`, this only seems to work for project source files and not project definition files.

Anyone know how I can set deprecation and warning for the compiler when it compiles the project definition?

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/xxx/website/project
[warn] there were 2 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] there were 4 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
[warn] two warnings found
```

Answer (score 8):

Create `project/build.sbt` project definition file with the following content:

```
scalacOptions := Seq("-feature", "-deprecation")
```

Since any `*.sbt` file under `project` belongs to the meta (build) project, it sets up the Scala compiler for the build configuration not the environment for the project under build.

It was tested with a sample sbt multi-project:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/multi-0.13.1/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[warn] /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/multi-0.13.1/project/Build.scala:4: method error in object Predef is deprecated: Use `sys.error(message)` instead
[warn]   lazy val e = error("Launcher did not provide the Ivy home directory.")
[warn]                ^
[warn] one warning found
```

...when it compiled the following `project/Build.scala`:

```
import sbt._

object Build extends Build {
  lazy val e = error("Launcher did not provide the Ivy home directory.")
}
```